# TypeORM - One to Many: EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "context.physicalPresets" was found

Tags: typeorm

I get the following error when updating `Project` entity: `EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "context.physicalPresets" was found`.

`ProjectContext` is embeded in `Project` as described here https://typeorm.io/#/embedded-entities. `ProjectContext` has a OneToMany relation to `Physical` entity.

```js
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseEntityModel {
  // embedded
  @Column(type => ProjectContext)
  context: ProjectContext;
}
```

```js
// embedded entity
@Entity()
export class ProjectContext {
  @OneToMany(type => Physical, physical => physical.project, {
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  physicalPresets: Physical[];
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class Physical extends BaseEntityModel {
  @ManyToOne(
    type => Project, project => project.context.physicalPresets,
    {onDelete: 'CASCADE'},
  )
  project: Project;
}
```

Not more success with:

```js
@Entity()
export class Physical extends BaseEntityModel {
 @ManyToOne(
    type => ProjectContext, projectContext => projectContext.physicalPresets,
    {onDelete: 'CASCADE'},
  )
  projectContext: ProjectContext;
}
```

I get `Entity metadata for Physical#projectContext was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options`.

```js
  async update(entity: Project): Promise<UpdateResult> {
    return await this.repository.update(entity.id, entity);
  }
```

Is it possible to have OneToMany relationship in an embed entity, if yes how?

Answer (score 7):

As the documentation explain, the update method of `Repository`:

> Updates entity partially. Entity can be found by a given conditions.
>   Unlike save method executes a primitive operation without cascades, relations and other operations included.

Using save method solve `No entity column [...] was found`.

```js
  async update(entity: Project): Promise<Project> {
    return await this.repository.save(entity);
  }
```

This is the correct way of doing OneToMany with embedded entity.

```js
@Entity()
export class Physical extends BaseEntityModel {
  @ManyToOne(
    type => Project, project => project.context.physicalPresets,
    {onDelete: 'CASCADE'},
  )
  project: Project;
}
```

See also: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/test/functional/cascades/cascade-insert-from-both-sides/cascade-insert-from-both-sides.ts